# Column names in each table must be unique. while copy table data from one table to another in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table `Transaction_tbl` with these columns:

```
transactid   Tbarcode     dtime

1            100          2013-04-16 14:15:47.243
2            101          2013-05-10 10:15:47.243
3            102          2014-02-20 02:15:48.000
```

In this table, `transactid` is the primary key.

I have one more table `KHanger_tbl` with these columns:

```
transactid   Hbarcode
1             21
2             22
3             23
```

in my `KHanger_tbl` this `transactid is the foregin key`

I want to move date range <=2013-12-30 data from `Transaction` table to another table called `Transaction2013..`  (i mean data in the 2013)

The same time corresponding `Khanger_table` data need to move to table called `Khanger2013`

I am creating a new table while executing query ..

First query

```
select * into Transaction2013
from Transaction_tbl
where dtime <='2013-12-30'
```

second query

```
select * into Khanger2013
from KHanger_tbl 
inner join Transaction_tbl
on Transaction_tbl.transactID=KHanger_tbl.transactid
where Transaction_tbl.dtime <='2013-12-30
```

but while executing the second query, I get an error:

> Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'transactID' in table 'Khanger2013' is specified more than once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using select * you are asking for all columns. As both tables have a transactionid this will then be created twice in the target table, which is not allowed. You need to use something like:

```
select k.transactid, k.Hbarcode into Khanger2013
 from KHanger_tbl k
inner join Transaction_tbl t
on t.transactid=k.transactid
where t.dtime <='2013-12-30
```

Comment: sir i want to move all columns from Khanger_tbl to Khanger2013..i dont want to move Transaction_tbl data to Khange2013

Comment: @user3252014 then use `select k.*` instead for just `*`

Comment: @user3252014 I have corrected the answer due to your comment

Comment: after copying data from original table i want to delete the same data from old table(i mean original table)..how i can do that sir?

Comment: That's another question @user3252014, please create a new question for this. (Or even better, check if there is already an answer on SO that helps you!)